# Aurelia: two templates added, second 404's

Tags: http-status-code-404, aurelia

I'm trying to set up multiple templates in Aurelia.  Currently, I have two custom templates.  No matter what I do, I am only able to load the first one I add.  The second returns a 404.

**For reference, here's my setup**

AureliaFile:

```
var aurelia = require('aurelia-cli');

aurelia.command('bundle', {
js: {
    'wwwroot/app-bundle': {
        modules: [
            'resources/main-content/main-content',
            'resources/side-menu/side-menu',
            'resources/index',
            'main',
            'app',
            'aurelia-framework',
            'aurelia-bootstrapper',
            'github:aurelia/loader-default@0.9.0',
            'github:aurelia/templating-binding@0.13.0',
            'github:aurelia/templating-resources@0.13.0',
            'github:aurelia/history-browser@0.6.1',
            'github:aurelia/templating-router@0.14.0'
        ],
        options: {
            inject:true
        }
    }
},
template: {
    'wwwroot/app-bundle': {
        pattern: '**/*.html',
        options: {
            inject:true
        }
    }
}
});
```

main.js:

```
export function configure(aurelia) {

    aurelia.use
        .standardConfiguration()
        .developmentLogging()
        .plugin('./resources/index');

    aurelia.start().then(a => a.setRoot('app'))

}
```

my `resources` folder (where my two templates are) looks like:

- resources

  - index.js
  - main-content

    - main-content.js
    - main-content.html
  - side-menu

    - side-menu.js
    - side-menu.html

and finally, my index.js is:

```
export function configure(aurelia) {
   aurelia.globalizeResources("./side-menu/side-menu");
   aurelia.globalizeResources("./main-content/main-content");
}
```

i have also tried changing it to:

```
export function configure(aurelia) {
   aurelia.globalizeResources(["./side-menu/side-menu", "./main-content/main-content"]);
}
```

**Now, my problem description**

No matter which I add first in my `index.js`, the second is not loaded.  After I run `aurelia bundle`, and load the site in the browser, I see:

[image]

**if i switch the load order, the other template 404's**.  If I include only one template in the `index.js`, the site loads fine, albeit without my second template.  Can someone please give me a pointer as to what I have missed?

Apologies for the long post, I wanted to give as much information as possible.

To add more description, in my Aurelia-built `appbundle.html` and `appbundle.js`, I see **both** templates, they look 100% correct as far as i can tell.

Comment: Maybe try: `aurelia.globalizeResources('./date-format', './number-format', './pager');`  This works for me.